# Getting 256 colors to work in tmux

Tags: colors, tmux, settings, konsole

I have 256 colors working just fine in `konsole,`. I thought I'd give `tmux` a try because, unlike screen, it seems to support `vi` mode.  However I find that the colors of my prompt show up and this is most likely because I have a 256 color mode prompt. What do I need to do to get `tmux` to recognize all 256 colors?

Comment: `tmux -2` I had to do this in *terminator* and I was somewhat surprised. The `-2` flag tells tmux to force the usage of 256 colors ... whether your terminal likes it or not ... dun dun dunnn :P

Answer (score 390, accepted):

The [Tmux FAQ](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki/FAQ) explicitly advises against setting TERM to anything other than `screen` or `screen-256color` or `tmux` or `tmux-256color` in your shell init file, so don't do it!

Here's what I use:

```
~$ which tmux
tmux: aliased to TERM=xterm-256color tmux
```

and in in my .tmux.conf:

```
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
```

Aliasing `tmux` to "`tmux -2`" should also do the trick.

And don't forget to restart your tmux server: (see [@mast3r answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/564360/302105))

```
tmux kill-server && tmux
```

Comment: I like the way to set it in the .tmux.conf best... using the shell to set it just doesn't seem right

Comment: Weird. You don't need `tmux -2` on OSX but you need it with Gnome Terminal. Thanks for the info, added to my aliases!

Comment: In Kubuntu 13.10 the .tmux.conf setting alone did not get me my 256 colors back (which took out highlighting in vim visual mode) but the alias worked. Would certainly prefer a .tmux.conf file only solution.

Comment: ssh'd into an Ubuntu machine (from OS X Terminal), the .tmux.conf default-terminal was all I needed.

Comment: Here is a relevant ticket: http://sourceforge.net/p/tmux/tickets/67/ ("tmux always sets TERM=screen").

There is an entry in `TODO` (source): "use screen-256color when started on 256 colour terminal?"

Comment: for me it seems like all I need to do is `TERM=screen-256color tmux` without creating a `.tmux.conf` file. Am I missing something?

Comment: 256 color reference: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/1/15/Xterm_256color_chart.svg

set status-bg colourX

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I was going crazy because text of some applications was being rendered as black text on a black background.

Comment: I lost color when I ssh'd into a different machine, this solves it!

Comment: and don't forget to restart the tmux server! tmux kill-server && tmux. Thanks to @mast3r

Comment: Tried each solution above (TERM=xterm-256color, `tmux -2`, and .tmux.conf) and only the .tmux.conf worked for me. Restarting tmux server is not required. I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.1.

Comment: `tmux kill-server` - I set everything neovim asked me to do and yet :checkhealth errors didnt go away after I changed my .tmux.conf. kill-server made the changes take place - thanks!

Comment: This is somewhat wrong.   `$TERM` outside of tmux (ie, before you launch it) MUST match your physical terminal (xterm-256color, vt100, etc).  `$TERM` inside tmux is what should be `screen*` or preferrably `tmux*` (but not everyone has a tmux term type installed globally).  Setting TERM=tmux before launching tmux only happens to work if your actual terminal is xterm based which is what `tmux-256color` was originally derived from.

Comment: Ty sir for this very beautifully done and straight forward solution, saved me from the rabbit hole of debugging `tmux`.

Answer (score 58):

Try setting 256 colors explicitly in your bashrc or zshrc:

```
export TERM=xterm-256color
```

or

```
export TERM=screen-256color
```

If you have problems with tmux not clearing the background colors correctly when using the screen term setting, you can try:

```
export TERM=screen-256color-bce
```

Comment: the first one is my default TERM setting... I just tried the other 2 and my prompt still doesn't show colors once I enter tmux. (I would like to note that tmux does show colors at the bottom)... it seems that when I enter tmux that it resets the TERM to TERM=screen... perhaps theres a way to override this in a config?

Comment: nvm... I guess putting it in a my shell's rc does work... how annoying that it ignores the TERM env variable that's set when I execute tmux... I guess I'll have to put a conditional in my rc.

Comment: -bce is not compatible with tmux.  Tmux does not support background color erase:

Comment: This (first one) is the only thing that worked for me so far, after trying lots of other suggestions.  Finally consistent!

Comment: This seems to be the only thing that works for me, too. I tried `tmux -2` + `set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"` without success. `export TERM=...` works out of the box, no need for either `tmux -2` or `set -g ...`. On Manjaro, btw.

Comment: I had this problem with roxterm. Hopefully adding roxterm to this will help people find the same solution that I had. I would end up in vim and selecting lines would make them dissappear. Extremely difficult to search for. roxterm by default sets up with just $TERM=xterm, which is no good.

Comment: -1, you shouldn't set either unconditionally in your shell initialization file. Setting it to `xterm-256color` will override it inside tmux as well, and setting it to `screen-256color` outside of tmux could lead to display bugs.

Comment: This advice is the only thing that worked for me running `tmux 2.1`, but caused other problems.  After upgrading to `2.6`, I was able to use `tmux-256color` and everything works much better

Answer (score 43):

As per the [tmux FAQ](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-use-a-256-colour-terminal), add this to your `~/.tmux.conf`:

```
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
```

Then add this alias for tmux:

```
alias tmux='tmux -2'
```

No need to override the `TERM` variable in your profile or when starting `tmux`.

More information: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/256_colors_setup_for_console_Vim

Comment: Configuring tmux was enough for me; I did not need to set alias (though it probably wouldn't hurt).

Comment: Configuring tmux alone works for me. The alias was not sufficient.

Comment: For me starting tmux with -u flag worked after setting the colors. So I created an alias as `alias tmux='tmux -u'`

Answer (score 26):

The newest version of ncurses ships with a *tmux-256color* terminfo entry (the [FAQ](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki/FAQ#why-do-you-use-the-screen-terminal-description-inside-tmux) does mention this). As an example, a benefit of using *tmux-256color* over *screen-256color* is that italics is properly rendered (screen doesn't support italics).

So if you are using `tmux 2.6` or above, and have the latest ncurses package, the following will work as well:

```
set -g default-terminal "tmux-256color"
```

Comment: I would note that this solution seems to require `tmux 2.6` or better

Comment: [tmux 2.7 works with this setting on fedora 29 for vim solarized dark scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10158508/lose-vim-colorscheme-in-tmux-mode/68982914#68982914) without any other settings in `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile`, `.vimrc`)

Answer (score 20):

For people who have latest tmux, the `.tmux.conf` option from the accepted answer should work.

I only want to add that you will probably need to restart tmux for the new configuration to take effect:

`tmux kill-server && tmux`

Interestingly, this isn't mentioned anywhere in the answers and took me a while to figure out.

Comment: not knowing about the server restart gobbled up a few hours of my life.

Comment: I just created account here to tell you that, it saved my life. I was about to giveup on tmux. But this ans saved tmux in my life ;) I can't upvote :(.

Comment: This just saved my life too after an hour of endless searching, felt like I was going insane. I'm going to propose this as an edit with credit to you in the top answer for visibility

Comment: WHY IS THIS THE ONLY PLACE THAT SAYS YOU NEED TO KILL TMUX?!

Anyway, you saved me. Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

I could not explain why this works but it solved the problem for me.

**~/.tmux.conf**

```bsh
set-option -g default-command bash
```

Comment: I tried this as the last resort and surprisingly it worked!

Comment: Yes! This solution also worked on 18.04 and 20.04. Thank you very much.

Comment: this actually solved the issue on Pop-OS 20.04

Answer (score 11):

Following lines in `~/.tmux.conf` worked for me --

```
set -g default-terminal "xterm-256color"
set-option -ga terminal-overrides ",xterm-256color:Tc"
```

Tested on

- Tmux 2.7, Ubuntu 16.04,18.04
- Tmux 2.9, CentOS
- Tmux 3.0a, CentOS7

Comment: Worked for me as well. Thanks! (Tmux 3.0a, Ubuntu 20.04, Terminal emulator: `Konsole`)

Comment: I've been searching for an hour and this was the only thing that worked for me. I'm running Arch with tmux v3.2a.

Comment: Nothing on so many questions, on so many other blogs, etc. worked. The second line of this answer worked. I am on CentOS7, tmux3.0a. First line is not required for me. my default $TERM = xterm-256color. added my configuration to the test configurations in the answer.

Comment: Worked for me as well, GNOME Terminal on Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 4):

Really important note here if you're running an Ubuntu older than Bionic (18.04).  If you're running `tmux 2.1` or older, and you probably are, basically no advice you read online about tmux will work..for anything.

`tmux -V` is an easy test for this.  If you see `2.1` or older, you can build tmux from source, or you can add an unofficial repository.  I updated my tmux with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:/hnakamur/tmux
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Personally, after upgrading to `2.6`, 1) my keys are working better, 2) online advice actually works, 3) my colors are not insane.  Big improvement.

(Here's a link to the repository page, btw):
https://launchpad.net/~hnakamur

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution....
I edit my .bashrc file and adding this

```
if [ "$TERM" != "xterm-256color" ]; then
      export TERM=xterm-256color
    fi
```

Hopefully it works in yours

Comment: Why bother with the `if`? You could just set the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Feeling grateful for all other answers here giving me hints, but then it seems unnecessary to modify global TERM setting AND `~/.tmux.conf`.

I ended up using an alias to set the TERM only when I'm about to use tmux. Just add this one-liner at the end of your `~/.bashrc` (or whatever shell configuration file you use).

```
alias tmux='TERM=xterm-256color tmux'
```

That's it. Interestingly, after tmux launchs, the TERM would automatically be reset to "screen", but the colors work anyway. So I guess tmux would also be happy (for not messing up with its TERM environment?).