# Terminal 256 colors don't work through Tmux

Tags: terminal, colors, tmux, gnome-terminal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting 256 colors to work in tmux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1045/getting-256-colors-to-work-in-tmux)

I want to set my terminal to 256 colors. I normally use the Gnome terminal which is shipped by default in Ubuntu but I also downloaded Terminator and tried Xterm and all them return 8 when I call `tput color` inside Tmux.

How can I arrange to have 256 colors in Tmux inside Gnome terminal so I can use Vim's 256-color scheme?

Comment: Try setting `TERM` to `xterm-256color`.

Comment: I found this, I added to the ~/.bashrc, working fine but once I tmux the setting goes off.

Comment: That would be a tmux problem.

Comment: I found help in #tmux channel on irc.freenode.net.

for 256 colors in tmux your 'echo $TERM' needs to return screen-256color and mine was returning screen. So i followed the instruction on this link https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Tmux#Setting_the_correct_term and everything worked.

Comment: @LuisDUrraca Please copy your answer to below and mark it as solved, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though OP answered the question in the above comments, I'll add the details here for easy reference. The quick solution is to add the following to your `.tmux.conf` file:

```
set -g default-terminal screen-256color
```

For more detailed info, check out the [Tmux page on ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Tmux#Setting_the_correct_term), or [this helpful answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1098/8431) to the same question.

Comment: It seems that having active sessions prevents new sessions from honouring the `default-terminal` option in .tmux.conf as well as passing `-2` as a parameter to `tmux`. Killing all sessions seemed to solve this for me.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Neither does using xterm instead of screen work.

Answer (score 2):

There is also the `-2` command line option for tmux - c.f. [older question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1045/getting-256-colors-to-work-in-tmux)