# Getting 256 colors to work in terminal multiplexer

Tags: terminal, gnu-screen, tmux, colors

## tmux

I followed [Getting 256 colors to work in tmux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1045/getting-256-colors-to-work-in-tmux):

- I have `alias tmux='TERM=xterm-256color tmux'` in `~/.bashrc`
- and also `set-option -g default-terminal "screen-256color"` in `~/.tmux.conf`

In `konsole`:

```
$ echo $TERM
xterm
```

In `tmux`:

```
$ echo $TERM
screen-256color
```

Still colors doesn't work in `tmux`:

```
boris@vasilisa:~$ PROMPT_GREEN=`tput setf 2`
boris@vasilisa:~$ PROMPT_RED=`tput setf 4`
boris@vasilisa:~$ PROMPT_BLACK=`tput setf 8`
boris@vasilisa:~$ PS1='\[$PROMPT_RED\]\w\[$PROMPT_GREEN\]:\[$PROMPT_BLACK\] '
```

Results in a black-and-white color prompt. Also no color with `ls`.

## screen

I have `force_color_prompt=yes` in `~/.bashrc`. Still:

```
boris@vasilisa:~$ PROMPT_GREEN=`tput setf 2`
boris@vasilisa:~$ PROMPT_RED=`tput setf 4`
boris@vasilisa:~$ PROMPT_BLACK=`tput setf 8`
boris@vasilisa:~$ PS1='\[$PROMPT_RED\]\w\[$PROMPT_GREEN\]:\[$PROMPT_BLACK\] '
```

Doesn't make prompt colorful. But in contrast to `tmux` -- `ls` lists files with color.

## So

I guess `tput setf` just shouldn't work with terminal multiplexers?

## Edit

I had to change `setf` to `setaf`, and also change the color codes:

```
PROMPT_BLACK=`tput setaf 0`
PROMPT_RED=`tput setaf 1`
PROMPT_GREEN=`tput setaf 2`
PS1='\[$PROMPT_RED\]\w\[$PROMPT_GREEN\]:\[$PROMPT_BLACK\] '
```

I don't need to aliase `tmux`, setting

set-option -g default-terminal "screen-256color"

in `~/.tmux.conf` is suffice.

So I put

```
# colorful prompt
PROMPT_BLACK=`tput setaf 0`
PROMPT_RED=`tput setaf 1`
PROMPT_GREEN=`tput setaf 2`
PS1='\[$PROMPT_RED\]\w\[$PROMPT_GREEN\]:\[$PROMPT_BLACK\] '

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto --group-directories-first'
    alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# man pages with color!
export LESS_TERMCAP_mb=$'\E[01;31m'
export LESS_TERMCAP_md=$'\E[01;31m'
export LESS_TERMCAP_me=$'\E[0m'
export LESS_TERMCAP_se=$'\E[0m'
export LESS_TERMCAP_so=$'\E[01;44;33m'
export LESS_TERMCAP_ue=$'\E[0m'
export LESS_TERMCAP_us=$'\E[01;32m'

# enable colors:
force_color_prompt=yes
```

in both: `~/.bashrc` and `~/.bash_login` and then colors work in `tmux`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well as you quite correctly guessed `setf` is not correct capability for setting foreground color in context of `xterm-256color`(`screen-256color`) terminfo entry. You should use `setaf` (set foreground color using ANSI escape).

```
$ echo $TERM
screen-256color

$ infocmp -1 | grep setf
$ infocmp -1 | grep setaf
    setaf=\E[%?%p1%{8}%<%t3%p1%d%e%p1%{16}%<%t9%p1%{8}%-%d%e38;5;%p1%d%;m,
```

Note:

1. you should not need to do `alias tmux='TERM=xterm-256color tmux'`, make sure your terminal emulator when started reports correct value of `TERM=xterm-256color`
2. if (1) is true then `tmux` will correctly set your `TERM` to `screen-256color` inside it, also it will for example correctly set it if you are running on linux console to `screen.linux`, there might be case you need to manipulate it but generaly not

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is putting the following lines in my .bashrc file:

```
    if [ "x$DISPLAY" != "x" ]
    then
        export HAS_256_COLORS=yes
        alias tmux="tmux -2"
        if [ "$TERM" = "xterm" ]
        then
            export TERM=xterm-256color
        fi
    else
        if [ "$TERM" == "xterm" ] || [ "$TERM" == "xterm-256color" ]
        then
            export HAS_256_COLORS=yes
            alias tmux="tmux -2"
        fi
    fi

    if [ "$TERM" = "screen" ] && [ "$HAS_256_COLORS" = "yes" ]
    then
        export TERM=screen-256color
    fi
```

Let me know if this helps.

---

Note that this solution is based on this [post](https://github.com/jcfaria/Vim-R-plugin/commit/a80c314ad55dc78e6386630218408298fbdfb988)!

Comment: This look like the changes jalvesaq [posted](https://github.com/jcfaria/Vim-R-plugin/commit/a80c314ad55dc78e6386630218408298fbdfb988) a few months ago. Did you get this from there?

Comment: Thank you, I didn’t see this. I got this solution send per mail a couple of weeks ago. I had some trouble with Vimux. I will edit the post and point to the page.

Comment: Looks like that was realy `setf` I used instead of `setaf`.