# Getting 256 colors to work with byobu

Tags: byobu

When I launch byobu, this always happens:

```
$ echo $TERM
screen
```

even if `$TERM` evaluates to `xterm-256color` outside of byobu.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 6):

Just set the `default-terminal` in profile.tmux:

```
$ echo 'set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"' >> ~/.byobu/profile.tmux
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cd /usr/share/byobu/profiles
sudoedit tmux
```

Find this:

```
# Cannot use:
#  - screen-bce, screen-256color-bce: tmux does not support bce
#  - screen-256color: vim broken without -bce
set -g default-terminal "screen"
```

...and change that to this:

```
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
```

You might be able to achieve the same result for your own account only without sudo powers by adding this command to `~/.byobu/tmux` but I have not tried this.

Comment: See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1045/getting-256-colors-to-work-in-tmux